# Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'jenkins', ignoring this repo error

Tags: jenkins, download, redhat, yum

I am installing Jenkins on redhat version 8 so i run below command as per suggested Jenkins official [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#prerequisites)

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo

sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
```

but when I run command

`yum install Jenkins`

its showing an error me error like this

`Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'Jenkins', ignoring this repo`

[image: error-log]

I have installed java 8 .

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: it is a part of machine learning and even i am deploying a machine learning code integrate with jekins @desertnaut

Comment: Please notice that tags have to do only with the *content* of the question, not its context; the fact that you may need help debugging, say, a computer vision model to be subsequently used onboard a spaceship does not qualify the question as being about `space-engineering`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my yum is perfectly working fine as i tried yum install python3 its working good but for jenkins it`s not working so that you have to download jenkins repo after download go to your terminal and run command rpm -ivh

Answer (score -1):

I would say the key part of your issue is the `Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'jenkins', ignoring this repo` error.

From my testing the size of the metadata that is downloaded when you use `yum` was about 18kB not the 13kB that is shown in your screenshot and so I think that the issue might be network connectivity or similar.

I'd suggest running `yum install --verbose jenkins` to see if that sheds any light on why it is failing to synchronize the repo cache.